# Drag and drop isn't working while creating menu

Tags: menus

I am creating a new site , in order to create menu , I just need to Drag and drop the item , in order to create exact menu position and sub menu . But Drag and drop isn't working . Thats why I am unable to create menu .  I disabled all the plugin , even deleted them . Even I use google libraries plugin . But non of them work , What can I do now  ? If there is any way to make menu alternatively . By the way drag and drop are working on widget edition , but doesn't work in menu editor .  I am using wp 3.6

Comment: The first thing you should do is disable your plugins and switch to a default theme. Try a different browser as well, and you _must have_ Javascript enabled in your browser. Some Ad Blockers or security software might interfere with the Javascript as well. You need to isolate the problem.

Comment: When I switched to default , it works , but when I use my theme it doesn't . I tried in every browser . when I work on my localhost , it doesn't have any problem . The problem occurs in server

Comment: Then your theme is apparently breaking something. What theme is it?